# Backbone .fetch() not updating collection with the latest data

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am attempting to update a filtered `video` collection when a `user` model makes a request to the server. The problem is in the `update` method. `fetch()` does not get the latest data for the `video` collection.

What do I need to fix in `update` to get the latest data so the view re-renders properly?

```
var VideosView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  id: 'video-list',

  initialize: function() {
    var user = this.model;
    var _videos = user.get('videos');
    user_vids = videos.filter_videos(_videos);

    this.listenTo(user, 'request', this.update);
  },

  render: function() {
    user_vids.each( this.addOne, this );
    return this;
  },

  addOne: function(video) {
    var videoView = new VideoView({ model: video });
    this.$el.append( videoView.render().el );
  },

  update: function() {
    $('#video-list').empty();
    _videos = this.model.get('videos');
    videos.fetch();
    user_vids = videos.filter_videos(_videos)
    user_vids.each( this.addOne, this );
  }
});

// Instantiate
var videosView = new VideosView({
  model: user,
  collection: videos
});
$('#allVideos').append( videosView.render().el );
```

**EDIT**

Adding additional code:

Here is where `videosView` is initialized.

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    user = this.model;
  },

  render: function() {
    var videosView = new VideosView({
      model: user,
      collection: videos
    });
    $('#allVideos').append( videosView.render().el );

    var addVideoView = new AddVideoView({
      model: user,
      collection: videos
    });
    $('#addVideo').append( addVideoView.render().el );
  }
});
```

The `listenTo` in `VideoViews` is listening for what is happening in `add_to_user_array` in
the `AddVideoView` here:

```
var AddVideoView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'div',

      template: _.template( AddVideoTemplate ),

      events: {
        'click #videoSubmitButton': 'submit'
      },

      initialize: function() {
        user = this.model;
      },

      render: function() {
        var template = this.template();
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
      },

      submit: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('form submitted');

        var vimeo_id = parseInt( $('#vimeo_id').val() );
        var newVideo = {vimeo_id: vimeo_id};

        this.collection.create(newVideo, {wait: true});
        this.add_to_user_array(vimeo_id);
      },

      add_to_user_array: function(vimeo_id) {
        var _videos = user.get('videos');
        _videos.push(vimeo_id);
        user.save({videos: _videos}, {wait: true});
      }
    });
```

Inside the router I'm instantiating the model and collection:

```
index: function() {
  users = new Users;
  users.fetch({
    success: function(user_data) {
      var user = user_data.findWhere({username: App.username})
      videos = new Videos;
      videos.fetch({
        success: function(video_data) {
          var indexView = new IndexView({
            model: user,
            collection: videos
          });
          var indexController = new IndexController;
          indexController.showView( indexView );
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: You reference the variable videos a couple of times which looks to me like it must be undefined. Check your console for any errors. I think you probably need to replace those with this.collection. On top of that I think you need to pass a callback function to the collection fetch method.

Comment: Thanks, but there are no errors or undefined errors. The data is simply stale.

Comment: `var _videos` is scoped inside the `initialize` method . And you are trying to access it  again inside update. Can you show the whole code instead of a partial view so that we can understand where exactly the problem is

Comment: Also these 2 lines make no sense `_videos = this.model.get('videos');
    videos.fetch();` The var `videos` is not defined inside the update function

Comment: Also what is the difference between `videos` and `_videos`

Comment: `videos` is `this.collection`. I added additional code to clarify.

Comment: Then what is `_videos`

Comment: `Videos` is a collection that has *all* the videos in the database.  That's initialized with `videos`. `_videos` is an array of video ids that are specific to the user. I am using a method in `Videos` called `filter_videos()` that takes `_videos` as its parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `fetch` is **Asynchronous**

So you are trying to filter the collection immediately after the fetch request. But the statements following them will simply execute immediately without waiting for the new data. You need to listen to the `reset` event or the sync event of the collection if you want the new data in hand. Also it is a better idea if you attach the common `attributes` to the view directly using `this` .. Try this

```
var VideosView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'video-list',

    initialize: function () {
        // Model
        this.user = this.model;
        // collection passed in
        this.videos = this.collection;
        // videos on model
        this._videos = user.get('videos');
        // filtered collection
        this.user_vids = videos.filter_videos(this._videos);
        // Listen to sync request on model
        this.listenTo(user, 'sync', this.update);
        // Listen to the video collection 
        // which will call the method once the collection is refreshed
        this.listenTo(this.videos, 'reset', this.resetVideos);
    },
    update: function () {
        $('#video-list').empty();
        _.delay( function() {
            // You already have access to videos
            // in the form of this.videos
            this.videos.fetch({reset: true});
        }, 100 );
    },
    resetVideos: function () {
        // Build the new user_vids collection from
        // newly fetch videos collection
        this.user_vids = this.videos.filter_videos(this._videos)
        this.user_vids.each(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function (video) {
        var videoView = new VideoView({
            model: video
        });
        this.$el.append(videoView.render().el);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.user_vids.each(this.addOne, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Let me know if the notes make sense or I misunderstood somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sushanth. I had to edit your suggested code by wrapping `video.fetch()` with `delay`, but this did the trick!

Comment: @EvanEmolo.. It is a common scenario where forget that such requests are `Asyn` and realize it later.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be listening to "sync" instead of "request"

request — when a model (or collection) has started a request to the server

sync — when a model (or collection) has been successfully synced with the server

by listening to request, you will only see the current data at the time of the request, not when the data has been synced and the collection updated.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. `videos.fetch()` did not update the collection to the latest data with `this.listenTo(user, 'sync', this.update);`